Majority element finding in leetcode
My code is running for most of the inputs, but for input:
nums = [6,6,6,7,7]

I am getting:
7 // Output, but expected 6

Can anyone tell me the incorrect part and correct suggestions?
class Solution {
    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        int count = 1;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 0;

        if (nums.length == 1) {
            return nums[0];
        } else {
            while (i < nums.length - 1) {
                if (nums[i] == nums[i + 1]) {
                    count++;
                    map.put(nums[i], count);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }

        int maxValueInMap = (Collections.max(map.values())); // This will return max value in the HashMap
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: map.entrySet()) { // Iterate through HashMap
            if (entry.getValue() == maxValueInMap) {
                return entry.getKey(); // Print the key with max value
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}


Add a few more sixes and sevens to the example and the try looking at the resulting maxValueInMap. Is it what you expected?

@OnstreamGaming, I see you were happy with the answer(s) given below. Why not marking an answer as accepted?

You only ever increment count, never resetting it when encountering a new value that differs from the previous one.

Thanks for your help , i have figured it out myself and now the code is running succesfully.

You can use Java streams and collect the integers into a frequency map.
This is a more idiomatic way to write it in modern Java.
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();

        int result = solution.majorityElement(new int[] { 6, 6, 6, 7, 7 });
        System.out.println(result); // 6

        int result2 = solution.majorityElement(new int[] { 6, 6, 7, 7, 5 });
        System.out.println(result2); // 6 (since there is a tie, we should probably return a list)

        // Print 7, because toFrequencyMap builds a LinkedHashMap, which preserves insertion order
        // If a HashMap was used instead, the value would most-likely be 6
        int result3 = solution.majorityElement(new int[] { 7, 7, 6, 6, 5 });
        System.out.println(result3); // 7 (since there is a tie, we should probably return a list)
    }

    public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
        return findByHighestFrequency(nums).stream()
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not determine max frequency!"));
    }

    private List<Integer> findByHighestFrequency(int[] nums) {
        final Map<Integer, Long> frequency = toFrequencyMap(nums);
        final long maxFrequency = Collections.max(frequency.values());
        return frequency.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxFrequency)
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Map<Integer, Long> toFrequencyMap(int[] nums) {
        return Arrays.stream(nums)
                .boxed() // Convert int stream to Integer stream
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(),
                        LinkedHashMap::new, // Supplier for the map
                        Collectors.counting() // Downstream collector that counts elements
                ));
    }
}

